# Google Chrome Javascript Link Bug

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When clicking a link in google chrome the focus event fails to fire.  All other browsers fire the focus event for links.

```
<a href=# onfocus="console.log('focus')">Link</a>
```

I do not want to attach the event onmousedown, but onfocus.

Anyone have an idea for a workaround.

**EDIT:**

I would definitely consider this a bug because all other focusable elements trigger focus on click.

Even non focusable elements with a `tabindex` trigger focus on click in google chrome.

```
<div tabindex="-1" onfocus="console.log('focus')">div</div>
```

I can't attach to both `click` and `focus` because then onclick, other browsers would call the function  twice.  I can't detect this functionality because it requires user
interaction, and I won't do user agent string detection, because well its wrong.

Using this html:

```
<a href=# onfocus="console.log('focus')" onmousedown="console.log('mousedown')">Link</a>
```

Is they any way to invalidate the second `onmousedown` call to prevent the function being called twice in non google browsers.

**EDIT 2:**

After some further testing `<input type=radio>` also fails to call focus in google chrome.
Why in the world is google chrome like this, while Opera, IE and firefox are all okay.  What is crazy is that the mobile webkit browser even triggers focus on links when I tried it on my Android device.

Comment: To check with the `tab` key: http://jsfiddle.net/82QXv/1/

Comment: @Heandel - I've got `12.0.742.100` and I don't see multiple focus events firing on tab. Can you try my fiddle in the above comment?

Comment: @Heandel - Very strange, since [using console.log()](http://jsfiddle.net/aaMuj/1/) doesn't fire it multiple times.

Comment: @Heandel - I don't know for sure, but it sure seems like it.

Comment: @Heandel @Jared Yeah I would file the continuous focus alert issue as a bug.  I had originally used alert only to have to force quit google chrome.

Comment: @Jared and OP: Filed a bug [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86724).

Comment: @Heandel - I added a note about the action associated with `alert()`'s. Also, *triggering* is the correct spelling... ;)

Comment: @Heandel - It happens. Shh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One work around you could do to avoid the double `focus` events from popping on the working browsers while still getting the `focus` event to pop on Chrome, is to on a click event check whether anything has `focus` on the page, and if not, then trigger the `focus` event.

With jQuery it could be done like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
     if(!$('*:focus').length) $(this).trigger('focus');         
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/qmcUt/

Comment: Interesting, it appears `document.activeElement` refers to document.body when triggering `onmousedown`, or `onclick` because to google chrome the element in fact never received focus.  http://jsfiddle.net/qmcUt/36/  Also I switched click to `mousedown` so it triggers when most browsers trigger `focus`.

Answer (score 3):

That actually works just fine, except that the focus event isn't triggered simply by clicking on the link (try tabbing and you'll see the event firing). I don't think it's a bug, why not just safe guard and use both?

Comment: +1. Webkit doesn't fire the event unless the user uses the keyboard.

Comment: @Triptych - I'm just wondering, why? The W3C seems to say it's ok for a "pointing device" to fire focus: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#adef-onfocus

Comment: I edited my post further explaining the issue, and why it should be filed as a bug.

Comment: @Triptych: That's not true. Webkit will fire the event for mouse events if the link has a `tabindex`. http://jsfiddle.net/7JzjT/

Answer (score 0):

You can use small hack:

```
<a href="#" onfocus="console.log('focus')" onclick="this.focus()">Link</a>
```